# query wikidata cities names in arabic and english

Tags: wikidata, wikidata-query-service

I need to get cities names in arabic and english from wikidata
also after that I need to get states names in arabic and english

is it available to download the query return data or copy it to excel or csv?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use Wikidata Query Service and receive labels in mutliple languages at the same time you have to repeat the `rdfs:label` Statement for each language like

```
SELECT * WHERE {
  ?item (wdt:P31/(wdt:P279*)) wd:Q515;
    rdfs:label ?cityLabelEN.
  FILTER((LANG(?cityLabelEN)) = "en")
  ?item rdfs:label ?cityLabelAR.
  FILTER((LANG(?cityLabelAR)) = "ar")
}
LIMIT 10
```

[Try It](https://w.wiki/5EXi)

If you want to get states instead of cities: change the first object from `wd:Q515` to `wd:Q7275` (and adopt the variabelname for the labels)